# Can I handle calculating/charging for shipping after order placed?

Tags: commerce

I am trying to determine if Drupal Commerce is the right ecommerce method to use for my client's project.

The workflow my client is looking for is:

1. Customer place order, and pays nothing for shipping.
2. My client will process order and determine shipping costs.
3. My client will charge customer for shipping, using CC data stored when they placed order.

Is this something that Drupal commerce can handle?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because Drupal Commerce 2.x and most payment gateway modules tokenize credit card details by default for the sake of reusable "stored payment methods." From a customer experience standpoint, you might want to offer some sort of estimated shipping amount, but so long as you're communicating that shipping costs will be calculated and confirmed with the customer prior to charging, there's not technical reason you could not charge the full amount during the fulfillment process.